# Meaning of “You get 12 weeks into it."

Tags: prepositions

A man says, “You get 12 weeks into it and you hit a wall” at 0:13 of the ABC News clip: https://ia600909.us.archive.org/29/items/KGO_20101216_013000_ABC_World_News_With_Diane_Sawyer/KGO_20101216_013000_ABC_World_News_With_Diane_Sawyer.mp4?start=1620&end=1680&ignore=x.mp4

I have a question relating to “You get 12 weeks into it."
If you say, "I get one day into it," do you mean that you started it yesterday, that you started it today, or that the present is somewhere between 24 and 48 hours since you started it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer that, since the time period he mentioned was not 'one day'. If someone said they were one day into something, you would have to work out from the context exactly what they meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get" here is the 'hypothetical present'. The speaker is describing about an imagined, likely, or common situation, and for this the present tense can be used. In the example sentence, the speaker is talking about a hypothetical person 'getting to' (arriving at) a time twelve weeks after they started something.

> Hypothetical situations
>
> When we talk about things that we imagine
> (hypothetical situations) we use present tense forms after phrases
> like what if, in case, suppose to talk about the future if we think
> that this is a situation that is likely to happen:

[Wishes and hypothetical situations](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/wishes-and-hypothetical-situations#:%7E:text=When%20we%20talk%20about%20things,umbrella%20in%20case%20it%20rains.)

[Suppose] you buy a box of 12 very sweet cakes, and start to eat them. You get four cakes in and you feel sick.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the 'hypothetical present'. In addition, I was wondering whether "You get 12 weeks into it" means that it is just 12 weeks after you started it. If you say "You get 1 week into it", is it just 7 days after you started it?

Comment: @JiHyunLee - I would say it could mean exactly 1 week or approximately 1 week.